# Is there a way to retain keys in Polars left join

Tags: python, left-join, python-polars

Is there a way to retain both the left and right join keys when performing a left join using the Python Polars dataframe library? Currently it seems that only the left join key is retained but the right join key gets dropped.

Please see example code below:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": [1, 2, 3],
        "bar": [6.0, 7.0, 8.0],
        "ham": ["a", "b", "c"],
    }
)

other_df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "apple": ["x", None, "z"],
        "ham": ["a", "b", "d"],
    }
)

df.join(other_df, on="ham", how="left")
```

In other data manipulation libraries this is possible for example using the R dplyr library you can do the below or even in standard SQL we can access the right join key in the `SELECT` clause.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  foo = c(1, 2, 3),
  bar = c(6.0, 7.0, 8.0),
  ham = c("a", "b", "c")
)

other_df <- data.frame(
  apple = c("x", NA, "z"),
  ham = c("a", "b", "d")
)

df %>%
  left_join(other_df, by = c("ham" = "ham"), suffix = c("", "_right"), keep = TRUE)
```

Comment: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/13130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible option :

```
out = (
    df.join(
        other_df.with_columns(pl.col("ham").alias("ham_right")),
        on="ham", how="left"
    )
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───────┬───────────┐
│ foo ┆ bar ┆ ham ┆ apple ┆ ham_right │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ f64 ┆ str ┆ str   ┆ str       │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 6.0 ┆ a   ┆ x     ┆ a         │
│ 2   ┆ 7.0 ┆ b   ┆ null  ┆ b         │
│ 3   ┆ 8.0 ┆ c   ┆ null  ┆ null      │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Oh yes creating a copy of the join column does workaround this but not streamlined in the box like dplyr or SQL. Looking to rewrite some SQL logic in Polars so bit of a gotcha!

Comment: @jeremyh `.name.suffix` can be used to avoid the need to name individual columns e.g. `pl.col("foo", "bar").name.suffix("_right")` - there's also no need to `left/right_on=` as just `on="ham"` would still suffice in this example.

Comment: to add to @jqurious's comment, what's actually happening is that it is dropping the `ham_right` that you're manually creating as part of the join and then it automatically notices that it has two `ham`s so it uses the default `suffix="_right"` to create `ham_right` again. To see that more clearly do `df.join(
        other_df.with_columns(pl.col("ham").alias("ham_55")),
        left_on="ham",
        right_on="ham_55",
        how="left"
    )` and the output will be the same. Better to only use the `on='ham'`

Comment: @jqurious, Dean MacGregor, I updated the answer to match your suggestion.